# What if there is a name collision when two models are associated?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When I associate two models, how do I prevent name collisions?

```
// Find all projects with a least one task where task.state === project.state
Project.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Task,
        where: { state: Sequelize.col('project.state') }
    }]
})
```

In this example, what if there was a name property in both project and task.

Comment: Above code throwing any error?

Comment: It's just a snippet from the documentation.